# Django DynamoDB Database backend

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, django-database

Is it possible to set up an AWS DynamoDB as the database backed for a Django server?
If so, how would I go about doing this?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best database solution for Django on AWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842961/best-database-solution-for-django-on-aws)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is there's no easy way. Django supports relational databases, but DynamoDB is NoSQL.

There doesn't appear to be a backend for django-nonrel, an unofficial fork for non relational databases.

If you want to use amazon to host the database, you could use their RDS service and configure Django as you would for MySQL.

Comment: Slightly OT, but how scalable are the RDS databases? I need something that can scale instantly.

Comment: That's too broad a question to answer here. There are already large websites using regular Django with relational databases. You'll have to do your own testing to see whether it's suitable for your use.

Comment: Also, RDS now supports PostgreSQL. So you can do that too

Comment: The new Aurora DB from AWS allows scaling out of the box even for writes.